# How to add an HTML widget through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, widget

When you copy and paste the tradingview chart widget HTML code (listed below) in your html file, the chart widget appears, however I need to add this widget code through javascript because in my project I need the widget to change based on the asset clicked by the user. So I need to destroy the current widget and add a new one through javascript, and I am struggling to accomplish this, this is the tradingview widget HTML code:

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="tradingview_fb869" style="height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget(
    {
    "autosize": true,
    "symbol": "BINANCE:ADABTC",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "save_image":false,
    "container_id": "tradingview_fb869"
    }
    );
    </script>
    </div>
```

And I tried to add this widget programatically through javascript by changing the innerHTML of a `div` element to the widget code string, but with no success:

```
var widgetCode=`
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="tradingview_fb869" style="height: 100%;"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget(
    {
    "autosize": true,
    "symbol": "BINANCE:ADABTC",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "save_image":false,
    "container_id": "tradingview_fb869"
    }
    );
    </script>
    </div>
    `;
    document.getElementById("widgetDiv").innerHTML=widgetCode;
```

So I ask how do I create this widget with javascript?

Comment: You should add widgetDiv div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a few more lines of code.
I guess you forgot add id property in your chart div
You can get a sample that works for you at [this link.](https://jsfiddle.net/2ntw1m0u/)

```
   <html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script>
   
      var fxWidget = new TradingView.widget({
     "autosize": true,
    "symbol": "BINANCE:ADABTC",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "save_image":false,
    "container_id": "tradingview_fb869"
    }); 
        document.getElementById("fxWidget").innerHTML=fxWidget;

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="fxWidget"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```